# Is https://www.asianwebdesigns.com/in/ a separate website?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, web

I just wondering whether `https://www.example.com/in/` is a subdirectory?

I have a website called `https://foobar.com` and I want to create separate website to uk client the same way here Asian Web Designs did.

Can anyone let me know how they did?

Comment: It's not necessarily a sub folder. It may be simply a url rewrite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: check screenshot]

In order to create a subdirectory in the website for different language or country, you have to install wordpress from cpanel or hpanel and you can install the wordpress in there and that's how you can create the subdirectory for different countries or languages.